# События мыши и клавиатуры.

Tags: события, javascript

Можно ли "перехватить" посредством javascript сразу два события - например, клик правой кнопки мыши при одновременно нажатой какой-то определенной клавиши на клавиатуре? (я не имею в виду стандартные ctrl и shift)

Comment: а что значит одновременно ? перехватывайте mousedown и keydown на документе, выставляйте флажёк  что там down на данный момент, на mouseup и keyup убирайте флажёк (можно один держать - down+, up-) когда оба down - событие одновременного нажатия случилось.

Comment: @eicto, а, ну да. спасибо. Протормозил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example: http://jsfiddle.net/davidexist/gFcuU/1630/

```js
var keys = {};

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    keys[e.which] = true;
    
    printKeys();
});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    delete keys[e.which];
    printKeys();
});

$(document).mousedown( function (e) {
 keys[e.which] = true;
  printKeys();
})

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    delete keys[e.which];
    printKeys();
});


function printKeys() {
    var html = '';
    for (var i in keys) {
        if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        html += '<p>' + i + '</p>';
    }
    $('#out').html(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click in this frame, then try holding down some keys :)

<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

может быть это поможет...

```js
var keys = {};

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    keys[e.which] = true;
    
    printKeys();
});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    delete keys[e.which];
    
    printKeys();
});

function printKeys() {
    var html = '';
    for (var i in keys) {
        if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        html += '<p>' + i + '</p>';
    }
    $('#out').html(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click in this frame, then try holding down some keys :)

<div id="out"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gFcuU/

Comment: Ваш код не работает.  Показывает один и тот же код клавиши независимо от нажатой мыши.

Comment: странно... у меня работает.